# Listexpander not working

Tags: javascript, css

my website the list expander is not working.  I think it might be because I changed the CSS, but I cannot figure out how to make it work.

Sorry the url is [http://hpcommtoolkit.com/Communication_tools.html][2] not the original.

```
[2]: http://hpcommtoolkit.com/Communication_tools.html
```

Comment: Instead of posting links that most people will not follow, create a minimalist self-contained page demonstrating the problem. Three reasons: 1. 90% of the time, you'll figure out the problem that way; 2. People won't accuse you of spamming; 3. It gives us, the people trying to help, a contained case to work with.

Comment: your updated example works perfectly fine here (FireFox 3)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what list you are referring to, however there is a fault in your HTML at line 405 with the style tag on the table which you should probably clean up:

```
style="BACKGROUND-IMAGE: url<img src="//images/afbottomgraphic.jpg"
```

The second double quote is ending the style tag prematurely. Background-image should be given a url in the form of `url(path-to-file)`.

EDIT: Ok, I see your expandable sections in the new URL. They work correctly in Firefox, but IE8 is generating the following error: "Object doesn't support this property or method listexpander.js, line 69 character 3".

Looking at that line of code, the first thing I can see is that the variable "li" should have a "var" declaration on it to avoid it interfering with any global vars. I would also recommend running listexpander.js through jslint (http://www.jslint.com/) since the syntax has a few oddly positioned semi-colons.

Comment: Thanks, I see that.  But my expand all/collapse all buttons are not working.  Are they working when you see it?  Maybe I should refresh and clear my cache.

Answer (score 0):

What list needs to be expanded? What code do you use for it?

Comment: well it works in FireFox. I advice you to make sure your HTML is valid first
http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fhpcommtoolkit.com%2FCommunication_tools.html&charset=(detect+automatically)&doctype=Inline&group=0

97 errors currently

The fact that your entire site consists of nested tables doesn't make it very easy to debug either